# Three js panorama viewer multiresolution images

Tags: javascript, three.js, 360-panorama

How to implement three js panorama viewer with multi resolution images, Like pannellum:https://pannellum.org/documentation/examples/multiresolution/.

**Current code is here using three.js:**(`//codepen.io/w3core/pen/vEVWML`).

1. From equirectangular image to panoroma viewer.
2. I have faced problem for high resolution images, takes long time to render.
3. When i seek some solution pannelum and Kprano solved this case by loading multi resolution images instead of single images.

So i tried to do loading multi resolution images instead of single equirectangular image.

**Solution i tried below:**

1. Converting single equirectangular image to  low resolution 6-cube map images.
2. And render those images like this sample.
   (https://threejs.org/examples/canvas_geometry_panorama.html)

   ```
   var materials = [
       loadTexture('px.jpg'), // right
       loadTexture('nx.jpg'), // left
       loadTexture('py.jpg'), // top
       loadTexture('ny.jpg'), // bottom
       loadTexture('pz.jpg'), // back
       loadTexture('nz.jpg')  // front
   ];
   mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(300, 300, 300, 7, 7, 7), materials);
   mesh.scale.x = -1;
   scene.add(mesh);
   ```
3. If zooming in any cube map image, i need to render my another medium level resolution images.

**Struck here**

How to proceed below things

1. How to render next level resolution images when zooming.

In Below sample zoom image...

I have made zoom 0 level but i couldnt make rendering zoom1,2,3 etc.

**Zoom : 0(Example of low resolution cube map front image)**

[image]

**Zoom: 1 (When zooming , Need to render next set of medium level resolution tile front images like below)**

[image]

**Zoom : 3 (When zooming further, Need to render next set of high level resolution tile front images like below)**[image]

**Zoom : 4 (When zooming , Need to render next set of very high level resolution tile front images like below)**[image]

Comment: Take a look at [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the link @pvg. Please have a look at my question now.

Comment: @AndiAR did you solve the issue?

Comment: No not @imudin07

Comment: If somebody solved please notify me

Comment: 5 years since then. Is this question still actual?

Comment: Finally got that working! See my answer below

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to work on a solution to the problem you are talking about for a couple of months now. It was not an easy one but finally got it working. I've created the threejs-based open-source package of the multiresolution panorama viewer. It is available here on GitHub: [Avansel Viewer](https://github.com/avansel/viewer) and documentation is [here](https://avansel.github.io/).

First, install the package:

```
npm i avansel
```

And here is an example of how to use it:

```
import { Avansel } from "avansel"

const container = document.querySelector('#avansel')

const params = [
    { tileSize: 374, size: 374, fallback: true },
    { tileSize: 512, size: 749 },
    { tileSize: 512, size: 1498 },
    { tileSize: 512, size: 2996 },
    { tileSize: 512, size: 5992 },
]

new Avansel(container)
    .multires(params, () => (s, l, x, y) => {
        l = parseInt(l) + 1
        return `/assets/images/multires-1/${l}/${s}${y}_${x}.jpg`
    }).start()
```

[Demo multiresolution panorama](https://avansel.github.io/examples/multires-1/)

Hope this would help. Let me know if you found any issues or need any ajsustmens of the script. I would be happy to help!